# Compiler throws error "undefined symbol" in C program

Tags: c, macos, unix, compiler-errors, header-files

I have the following in `test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdfn.h"

int main(void)
{
    printOut(10, "Hello, world!\n");
    //bash("say hello world");
}
```

Source is here:
https://github.com/KrasnayaSecurity/HydroCarbon

I get this error when I try to compile:

```
President-JohnHEden:HydroCarbon aleksandr$ gcc test.c -o test -Wall
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_printOut", referenced from:
      _main in test-134873.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please make sure you keep your function declarations in .h and definitions in .c . I see .h including #include "stdfn.c" why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here, your linker is not able to find the definition of `printOut()` function.

You have included the declaration of `printOut()` in your `test.c` file by inlcuding `stdfn.h`, but there is no definition fpr that function present in `test.c`. The definition is present in `stdfn.c`. So, you need to complie both the files together to produce the binary.

Change your compilation line to

```
gcc test.c stdfn.c -o test -Wall
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
gcc test.c stdfn.c -o test -Wall
```

(presuming stdfn.c is the where the definition of printOut() lies) so as to link the file containing the user defined function to the file thats currently using it.